# How to implement System.currentTimeMillis() method in WPF?

Tags: c#, wpf

I'm trying to create a unique TranactionID using `${=System.currentTimeMillis()}` in WPF textbox like following :

```
writer.WriteStartElement("TransactionId");

writer.WriteString(textBox22.Text);

<TextBox x:Name="textBox22" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="23" 
Margin="388,392,0,0" TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="${=System.currentTimeMillis()}" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="120"/>
```

Any idea how to implement it correctly?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to make time as a Transaction id so you can use builtin functionality of core .net framework. like this one:

```
DateTime.Now.Millisecond.ToString();
```

Comment: The Java method `System.currentTimeMillis()` returns the number of milliseconds elapsed since Midnight January 1 1970 (UTC). Your suggestion returns the number of milliseconds elapsed since midnight in the local time zone.

Comment: That's right Martin , but since this method fulfills its purpose for creating a unique ID so it´s ok for me.

Answer (score 0):

```
${=
```

is NOT a wpf syntax you should learn WPF first.
you should bind your text to a viewmodel property.
the proper way to get unique TranactionID is

```
Guid.NewGuid();
```

System.currentTimeMillis is java method.

Comment: Right its a java method , well i did not formulate your question correctly, I actually didn`t know where to call that method but it was easy to figure it out . thanks for the help